# problem with multiple global ipv6 adresses

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ipv6

(first sorry for my bad english)

as I don't get any answers from the ubuntu forum about my problem I go post here. I don't work at the moment with any linux host, I only use VM(debians and ubuntus). 
So I don't know if the problem comes from the virtualization with virtualbox or from inside the distribution or from my router.

The problem is: after a while, I get several global ipv6 addresses. only one is good but the route didn't seem to update correctly so i can't get a "ping6 ipv6.google.com" working for example. Only if I do "dhclient -6", then it comes with only one ipv6 in the stack.

Apparently the problem doesn't appear with windows hosts or windows guests (only one ipv6 at all time). The rule that we get 2 global ipv6 addresses (one with the MAC and one public) is not true anymore (only true on my routers).

The problem is more frequent on 14.04 than debian 8.2 or ubuntu 15.04. 
So I don't know if it's a distro problem, a problem of configuration with my router(but then why it doesn't appear with windows and why not more frequently), or a virtualization problem (maybe the new virtualbox 5 don't send correctly ipv6 information to guests?). I even don't know how to diagnose it.

By the way, the old ipv6 which are in ifconfig results, are also of course in route -6 . Also I get my ipv6 by dhcp and the ifconfig is as simple as :"iface eth0 inet6 dhcp dns-nameservers 2001:4860:4860::8888"

For example, why is this happening?

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:2d:04:e0  
      inet addr:192.168.5.74  Bcast:192.168.5.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
      inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:2a74:4900::29d4:52c8/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:2a27:bd00::29d4:52c8/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:2a1b:ce00::29d4:52c8/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:2a43:3200::29d4:52c8/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe2d:4e0/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:8679158 errors:0 dropped:12 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6032711 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:11731459169 (11.7 GB)  TX bytes:15029038568 (15.0 GB)
```

that's the route -6 results

```
2a02:a03f:2a1b:ce00::/64       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
2a02:a03f:2a27:bd00::/64       ::                         UA   256 0     0 eth0
2a02:a03f:2a43:3200::/64       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
2a02:a03f:2a74:4900::/64       ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
fe80::/64                      ::                         U    256 0     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   285 lo
::1/128                        ::                         Un   0   4    81 lo
2a02:a03f:2a1b:ce00::29d4:52c8/128 ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
2a02:a03f:2a27:bd00::29d4:52c8/128 ::                         Un   0   1    10 lo
2a02:a03f:2a43:3200::29d4:52c8/128 ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
2a02:a03f:2a74:4900::29d4:52c8/128 ::                         Un   0   1     0 lo
fe80::a00:27ff:fe2d:4e0/128    ::                         Un   0   1    77 lo
ff00::/8                       ::                         U    256 1     0 eth0
::/0                           ::                         !n   -1  1   285 lo
```

So if anyone have some enlightment about this thing, would be great?

Here another example of another vm right now after a restart, really don't know why it does that :

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:94:02:f0  
      inet addr:192.168.5.80  Bcast:192.168.5.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
      inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:2a27:bd00::216b:28cf/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:2a43:3200::216b:28cf/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe94:2f0/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:2a74:4900::216b:28cf/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:2a27:bd00::2b90:ea1f/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: 2a02:a03f:2a1b:ce00::216b:28cf/64 Scope:Global
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4639 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:293 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:361329 (361.3 KB)  TX bytes:40194 (40.1 KB)
```

Comment: Wait wait wait wait ... wait. You get **multple** **global** IPv6 addresses from your **router**? Is your "router" an internet backbone by any chance or what?

Comment: Multiple addresses with the same or different prefix?

Comment: @nephente I've put an example from one of my VM on ubuntu 14.04.3

Comment: @Wolfer I'm a simple final-user so my router can't possibly be an internet backbone, no? but like I said I've just put an example of what's happening. And according to my router the good one that had been assigned is the 2a27:bd00 for another 2 hours(lease). and of course I can't do a ping6 atm

Comment: @Wolfer and why shoudn't I get several global ipv6 address? You always receive a block of ipv6 address from your provider, big enough to address all the hosts even the mobile no? At least for my case it's /56 prefix that my router ask to the provider

Comment: As I said it depends on who you are and what you are doing, but a normal home user (in my country) only gets a single IP from an ISP. Also I sort of associated the word Global with the whole `internet accessible` thing, instead of the strict IPv6 `Global` term. My bad.

Comment: @wolfer no problem. In my country, your logic is the same but for ipv4 not ipv6 and we receive a block of addresses. Here it s a dhcp by prefix délégation.  Do each host have an ipv6 global which is accessible from the outside.

Comment: the two pack of information that I gave is from the two Ubuntu vm 14.04. Nothing happened on the other vm. I will continue to monitor the behaviour.

Comment: All I know at the moment that according to my router one of the two vm ask for 2 ipv6 at the same time not long ago and a third one several hours ago. But there is only one address lease to the other vm (again according to my router)